# Making Rails.logger tee writes to stdout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

My Rails.logger works nicely, thank you very much, but I would *also* like it to write to STDOUT (that is, not to give up logging to logfiles, but to "Tee" it to stdout).

Is this possible in Rails 3?

Comment: What’s wrong with `tail -f $YOUR_LOG_FILE`?

Answer (score 1):

This simple delegating logger should(*) do the trick:

```
class MultiLogger
  def initialize *loggers
    @loggers = loggers
  end

  def method_missing *args, &blk
    @loggers.each {|l| l.send *args, &blk }
  end

  def respond_to_missing? *args
    @loggers.all? {|l| l.respond_to? *args }
  end
end

Rails.logger = MultiLogger.new Rails.logger, Logger.new($stdout)
```

(*) I haven't tried it

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not work: more is written to console than to logfiles - in my case only sql statements get logged while console also contains results of plain "puts" and pretty printers (PP.pp). Though I'm not sure this is the fault of the code here, because legacy code is messing with logging quite a lot.

Comment: Well, clearly your logging isn't all going through the logger. You haven't explained why you need this functionality.  Can't you just use external tools, eg: `tail -f`?

Comment: You might be able to cheat on the non-logger logging using `ObjectSpace#each_object` to find all `File` objects that are open to your log file and reopen them to a pipe `|tee logfile`.

Comment: well a bit of legacy + ad hoc diagnostics goes to STDOUT and not to Rails.logger. This causes me do synchronized reading of console and log which is tedious and rather frustrating experience. Getting everything into one stream, either logfile or console would be fine, but technically it's the same (still one stream) and console is more convenient, esp. since I'm using RubyMine that highlights source code lines.